# Decimate mesh without losing smooth shading

Tags: modeling

I have an fbx file of a car model I purchased from unity store.
The mesh is triangulated and vertex count is 120K. 
I need to bring it down to 30K .
Here is the things I tried.
1) used instant meshes but It doesnt work well with rim and tyres and wiper etc. 
2) brought mesh in to zbrush and zremeshed it . It ruined small parts of the car. So second time I brought only large parts of the mesh and It went fine.

But still I could reduce only 30K vertex.
My last option was to defimate every thing by factor of 0.5 .
Thus I reached the target but It ruined all my smooth shading when I imported it in to unity and 30-40% of my mesh looks black.

Right now retopology looks best option for me. But I have to do same thing for 20 another models. It is going to take lot of time and money. 
What do you suggest?

Comment: Retopology does looks like the best option to be honest, you could try to transform tris to quads (alt+J i believe), that might open a way for some quick loop dissolving that would bring the poly count lower.

Comment: @internetofmine thank you. I think modeling everything from scratch looks better option now . At